# iphone , how to parse a xml file

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone XMLParser help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664831/iphone-xmlparser-help)

hi..
since im new to iphone, i dont know how to parse a xml file. can anyone help me out

Comment: Have you checked any parsers available? (e.g. standard: NSXMLParser, libxml, 3rd party: TouchXML, etc etc...)

Comment: Same question, different day: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507547/how-to-use-nsxmlparser) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138707/are-there-good-and-easy-to-understand-tutorials-on-nsxmlparser) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097631/how-to-read-in-and-parse-an-xml-file-on-the-iphone) [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797996/simple-method-to-read-xml-from-a-url-iphone) [5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664831/iphone-xmlparser-help) [...](http://www.google.com/search?ie=utf8&oe=utf8&q=site:stackoverflow.com+xml+iphone+parse)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at NSXMLParser
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html
It should help you out..

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample code from Apple.. It shows the difference between All XML parsers available..

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/XMLPerformance/Introduction/Intro.html

For a newbie it will be real helpfull..Feel free to use it..

Answer (score 0):

It's quite old, but you should read http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project This can help you.

Or open Xcode's help (Xcode - Help - Documentation and API Reference) and search for SeismicXML. This is sample from iOS SDK. There are also samples like XMLBrowser, XMLPerformance, ...