# How to use NSXMLParser?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, nsxmlparser

I have some XML which I need parsed in my Objective-C code.  The XML is fairly simple.  I have already searched Stackoverflow as well as Google but I did not find what I am looking for. Examples if how to use NSXMLParser would be useful, and if anyone has any suggestions on how to do this another way please let me know.

Comment: There are many tutorials out there. What exactly are you looking for.. this question maybe possible duplicate.

Comment: I looked at other questions, but I did not find exactly what I am looking for.  I am looking for a specific example of how to use NSXMLParser.  Please let me know if you find a duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there good and easy to understand tutorials on NSXMLParser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138707/are-there-good-and-easy-to-understand-tutorials-on-nsxmlparser)

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138707/are-there-good-and-easy-to-understand-tutorials-on-nsxmlparser, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797996/simple-method-to-read-xml-from-a-url-iphone, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664831/iphone-xmlparser-help

Comment: Thanks, did not see that.  I do not have time to read it now, but it looks like what I was looking for.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Did you look at the Apple sample applications? From the [NSXMLParser class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html), I found no fewer than five sample projects that did parsing.

- [GKTank](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GKTank/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008918)
- [KMLViewer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/KMLViewer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010046)
- [LazyTableImages](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394)
- [SeismicXML](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SeismicXML/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007323) (probably your best bet, and most directly related)
- [XMLPerformance](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/XMLPerformance/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008094)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend going through this tutorial by Ray Wenderlich:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml

It uses GDataXML, which from my experience is a light-weight easy to use XML parser. It goes through all the basic steps to read and write to an XML document in a specific directory, including making or ammending to the file if it doesnt exist or exists respectively.